# Generic Delegates that accept an object and return another

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Consider the following class

```
public static class ObjectHelper 
{
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;

    public static Func<T, T> Clone = (obj) => Deserialize<T, T>(obj);

    public static Func<TIn, TOut> Deserialize = (obj) => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TOut>(obj.ToJson());
}
```

The `Clone` and `Deserialize` declarations are invalid. I googled a bit but I can't seem to find how to write them correctly. I am sure I am missing something simple.

I intend to achieve the following

- To easily switch out the body of the `Deserialize` method. Currently its using the class from the MongoDb C# driver. I would like to be able to switch it to use say JSON.Net instead. Lets not worry about whether or not there is a valid reason to do this or about any better means of doing it. In my real world problem, I have worked around it and moved on. I am simply interested in learning whether I can write code like the above or not.

I added the `Now` to demonstrate code that works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The reason the first one, `Now`, works, is because it is not generic.*

You've got some issues here.

- You are not specifying any information (constraints) about your generic types;
- For example, how possibly does Deserialize know whether obj (of type TOut) has a method, ToJson?
- Further, you have 3 generic types: T, TIn, and TOut. They are not declared anywhere! And, one of them isn't needed.
- When declaring a lambda with an input parameter do not use parens `()`, just use the variable name

**Some examples to fix the issues:**

1. Here's the proper way to declare a Lambda that takes a parameter:

   ```
   // No input parameter, use ()
   public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;

   // Input parameter(s), just name them and put them after the = sign
   public static Func<string, DateTime> Now = s => DateTime.Now;
   ```
2. In order for a generic type to be able to use a method, it has to implement an interface and/or have a constraint that it inherits a base class containing that method:

   ```
   public interface HasJson
   {
       string ToJson();
   }

   public static class ObjectHelper<TIn, TOut>
       where TIn : HasJson // now you can call ToJson() method on type TIn
   ```
3. You only need 2 generic types, TIn, and TOut; T is not needed because Clone takes the same input and returns the same output as Deserialize. Here's an example with test code that works:

   ```
   public static class ObjectHelper<TIn, TOut>
       where TOut : class, new()
       where TIn : HasJson
   {
       // This Lambda is not generic; it'll work wherever you put it :)
       public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;

       // Clone takes TIn, and returns the output of Deserialize, which is TOut;
       // Therefore Clone and Deserialize will have the same generic type parameters
       public static Func<TIn, TOut> Clone = obj => Deserialize(obj);

       // calling obj.Json only possible due to where TIn: HasJson constraint above
       public static Func<TIn, TOut> Deserialize = obj => FakeBSON(obj.ToJson());

       // Just to test a method call in the generic lambda, meant to mimic what BSONSerializer 
       // does and allow my test code to compile without having BSONSerializer available
       static TOut FakeBSON(string json)
       {
           var res = new TOut();
           return res;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to add the type constraints to each method, but they weren't compiling. I forgot I could them to the class instead :P